# jboss equivalent ant wlappc

Tags: ant, jboss, weblogic

i am trying to migrate java apps running on weblogic to jboss 7 , during ant build there are few   ant tasks of specific to weblogic

```
<taskdef name="wlappc"    classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
<taskdef name="xjc"       classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask"> 
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
</taskdef>
```

are there any jboss equivalent for above mentioned ant tasks .

much appreciated for your timely response .Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apps merely [compiles](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=573) a WAR.

XJC creates JAXB bindings from WSDLs it finds on the class path. Also, it's not weblogic-specific.

You should not have problems finding equivalent ant tasks for JBoss.